# select one/sevral more row for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a set of supply operation organised like this:

```
op_type  |  time_stamp  |  product | in  | out
----------------------------------------------------
01       |  08:00:00    | p1       | 50  | 0  
02       |  08:01:00    | p1       | 0   | 10  
02       |  08:02:00    | p1       | 0   | 35  
03       |  08:03:00    | p1       | 0   | 5  
01       |  08:04:00    | p1       | 60  | 0  
02       |  08:09:00    | p1       | 0   | 15  
01       |  08:10:00    | p1       | 30  | 0  
02       |  08:11:00    | p1       | 0   | 20  
01       |  08:00:00    | p2       | 100 | 0  
02       |  08:01:00    | p2       | 0   | 20  
02       |  08:02:00    | p2       | 0   | 45  
03       |  08:03:00    | p2       | 0   | 15  
01       |  08:03:10    | p2       | 60  | 0  
01       |  08:04:00    | p2       | 5   | 0  
02       |  08:09:00    | p2       | 0   | 30  
01       |  08:10:00    | p2       | 30  | 0  
02       |  08:11:00    | p2       | 0   | 10
```

What I want is to select the list witch the `SUM(in) group by product` will cover the `SUM(out) group by product` starting from a given time
EX: for `time_stamp>'08:05:00'` I have :

`SUM(out) for p1=35` so the sum
and `SUM(out) for p2=40`

so the list I want to get would be

```
op_type  |  time_stamp  |  product | in  | out
----------------------------------------------------
01       |  08:04:00    | p1       | 60  | 0  
02       |  08:09:00    | p1       | 0   | 15  
01       |  08:10:00    | p1       | 30  | 0  
02       |  08:11:00    | p1       | 0   | 20 
01       |  08:03:10    | p2       | 60  | 0  
01       |  08:04:00    | p2       | 5   | 0  
02       |  08:09:00    | p2       | 0   | 30  
01       |  08:10:00    | p2       | 30  | 0  
02       |  08:11:00    | p2       | 0   | 10
```

what i did is that i added tow column to the result witch one has the sum of `out` and the other has the cumulative sum of `in`

```
 SELECT B.*,C.sum_out  FROM (SELECT A.*,SUM(in) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp desc) AS sum_in FROM table A) B
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 SELECT C.* FROM (SELECT product,SUM(out) AS sum_out from table GROUP BY product WHERE time_stamp>'08:05:00') C
 ON B.product=C.product
```

so I get :

```
op_type  |  time_stamp  |  product | in  | out  | sum_in  | sum_out
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
01       |  08:00:00    | p1       | 50  | 0    | 140     | 35
02       |  08:01:00    | p1       | 0   | 10   | 90      | 35
02       |  08:02:00    | p1       | 0   | 35   | 90      | 35
03       |  08:03:00    | p1       | 0   | 5    | 90      | 35
01       |  08:04:00    | p1       | 60  | 0    | 90      | 35
02       |  08:09:00    | p1       | 0   | 15   | 30      | 35
01       |  08:10:00    | p1       | 30  | 0    | 30      | 35
02       |  08:11:00    | p1       | 0   | 20   | 0       | 35
01       |  08:00:00    | p2       | 100 | 0    | 195     | 40
02       |  08:01:00    | p2       | 0   | 20   | 95      | 40
02       |  08:02:00    | p2       | 0   | 45   | 95      | 40 
03       |  08:03:00    | p2       | 0   | 15   | 95      | 40 
01       |  08:03:10    | p2       | 60  | 0    | 95      | 40 
01       |  08:04:00    | p2       | 5   | 0    | 35      | 40
02       |  08:09:00    | p2       | 0   | 30   | 30      | 40
01       |  08:10:00    | p2       | 30  | 0    | 30      | 40
02       |  08:11:00    | p2       | 0   | 10   | 0       | 40
```

If I add the clause `WHERE B.sum_in<=C.sum_out` i would be able to get

```
op_type  |  time_stamp  |  product | in  | out  | sum_in  | sum_out
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
02       |  08:09:00    | p1       | 0   | 15   | 30      | 35
01       |  08:10:00    | p1       | 30  | 0    | 30      | 35
02       |  08:11:00    | p1       | 0   | 20   | 0       | 35
01       |  08:04:00    | p2       | 5   | 0    | 35      | 40
02       |  08:09:00    | p2       | 0   | 30   | 30      | 40
01       |  08:10:00    | p2       | 30  | 0    | 30      | 40
02       |  08:11:00    | p2       | 0   | 10   | 0       | 40
```

So I will need one more row for each product.

Any idea how to perform this??
PS: I'm using SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: what is the significant of time `08:05:00` ? is it an input to the query ?

Comment: yes it is, and dont get worried about time format this is just a dummy data

Comment: What is your final output that you want

Comment: the second table in the question

Comment: what is the logic here ? the starting time is `8:05` and the result you wanted includes time earlier than `8:05` ?

Comment: the point is to bind an `out` operation with an `in` operation (inventory FIFO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I drafted a possible solution, you can use subqueries to get all the accumulated transactions

```
            Select time_stamp, 
        (Select Sum(SQ.InEntry - SQ.OutEntry)  from Table_1 AS SQ where T.time_stamp > SQ.time_stamp AND T.product = SQ.product group by product) +
            InEntry - OutEntry 
            , T.InEntry
            , T.OutEntry
            , product 
            from Table_1 T
            order by product,time_stamp
```

To generate random data I used this statement

```
            declare @FromDate date = '2016-01-01'
            declare @ToDate date = '2016-12-31'
             declare @product varchar(50)
             set @product = ( select top 1  A.Prod from (Select 'A' AS Prod union all select 'B' AS Prod union all select 'C' AS Prod) AS A order by newid())

            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
                       ([time_stamp]
                       ,[product]
                       ,[InEntry]
                       ,[OutEntry])
            Select
            dateadd(day, 
                           rand(checksum(newid()))*(1+datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)), 
                           @FromDate)
            ,@product
            ,0
            ,ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 100)


            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
                       ([time_stamp]
                       ,[product]
                       ,[InEntry]
                       ,[OutEntry])
            Select
            dateadd(day, 
                           rand(checksum(newid()))*(1+datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)), 
                           @FromDate)
            ,@product
            ,@product ,ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 100)
            ,0
            GO 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be grouping by product?
Anyway this may help, you can do your normal aggregates using SUM & GROUP BY grouping on what ever with the appropriate WHERE clause  on the time.

But to get what you ask...

> SUM(in) group by product will cover the SUM(out)

....you can use HAVING.....

Eg

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, SUM(IN), SUM(OUT)
FROM Table
WHERE Your_where_clause
GROUP BY Field1, Field2
HAVING SUM(IN) >= SUM(OUT)
```

Comment: It will get me all the table.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that HAVING will do what you want if you have the grouping and where done.

Comment: May be my explanation was a little bit poor. in fact the table has an in_price, and every supply out will be point with a supply entry (in) till the entry amount end (FIFO), so i'm trying to do a cumulative sum of the entry from the end of the table by :`SUM(in) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp desc)` and compare it with the sum of out by :`SUM(out) AS sum_out from table GROUP BY product` .so I'm doing the gouping by OVER (PARTITION BY and GROUP BY
And neither SUM(IN) >= SUM(OUT) nor SUM(IN) <= SUM(OUT) wil get me the result i want